# Find out rss feed link from the rss feed item link

Tags: xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rss, zapier

I am using Zapier to poll multiple RSS feeds and storing new RSS feed items into Firebase. Here are the details of item I get from Zapier.

[image]

But there is a problem, I am not getting which RSS feed the item has been fetched.

For processing further logic, I want to find out the RSS feed's actual link from which the RSS feed item has been fetched.

Is there a way to find out RSS feed link from the item's link?

e.g. From this [Sample Item Link](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/economy/agriculture/sugar-price-rise-inevitable-due-to-sugarcane-frp-hike-nfcsf/articleshow/58842741.cms) I should be able to get this [RSS feed Link](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1202099874.cms)

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Code by Zapier" step that analyzes the `link` URL to determine the feed source. Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKIho.jpg

```
var feed = "N/A";

if (inputData.link.startsWith('http://economictimes.indiatimes.com')) {
    feed = "indiatimes";
} else if (inputData.link.startsWith('http://some-other-site.com')) {
    feed = "other";
}

output = [{feed: feed}];
```

Then your next step can analyze what "feed" value is, and decide how to proceed.

Comment: I may have multiple RSS feeds from same domain so this approach doesn't help in my case.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the link exactly; the point here was to illustrate how you can look at anything in the feed to determine the source. Surely, the `<channel><title>` value would be unique per feed?

Comment: That's the problem Matt. I am not getting `<channel><title>` or anything unique in the response which I receive from Zapier.

Comment: Ah, I also realized after testing that Zapier only includes individual `<item>` data, as opposed to the parent tags (`<channel><title>…</title>`, etc), so unless you have some unique identifier within each feed `<item>`, this option won’t work.

Comment: I have decided to switch to [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/). It doesn't store data to Firebase, so I have created cloud function to push data in Firebase whenever push notification is received from Superfeedr.